# ODATA Can't combine two or more groups with or operator

Tags: filter, odata, grouping, odata-v4, or-operator

I'm trying to query Accounts from NAV2017 with OdataV4.

**For your background** but not directly related to the actual problem:

I have written a function to do a query and return an object. When querying I want to filter the list by the property 'No'(String). My input could be a string like "1600-1699" or "1600-1699,2000-2099" and so on. That's why I need to be flexible with my function and the ODATA query.
I have tried the following with my function and also with Insomnia (which is very much like Postman). The results are the same, so the problem is not my code.

**The actual problem**:

The filter should be a range so I try the following:

```
http://myaddress/.../AccountList?$filter=(No ge '1600' and No le '1699')
```

This works perfectly fine. **But** if I try to add another range like:

```
http://myaddress/.../AccountList?$filter=(No ge '1600' and No le '1699') or (No ge '2000' and No le '2099')
```

I get:

> **501 "The OData filter expression is not supported."**

**My Question**:
Why can't I combine two or more filter groups like I did above with the `or`-operator?
Is there another way on how I could achieve my goal?

Thank you.

**Btw.** leaving out the parantheses/brackets has no impact.

Comment: That syntax is OData v4 compliant and works against many implementations. It looks like NAV2017 does not support `OR` in which case you might consider pulling the outer range and filtering the rest on the client, or making two separate requests. Some implementations do not even support `ge` and `le` on string types, so at least you've got that support.